# D3 v4 Scaling Data to Range

Tags: d3.js, range, scale

Data is not correctly scaling to range.

I am appending an svg to a div,

```
var svg = d3.select("#box")
          .append("svg")
          .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
```

and then a group to that svg.

```
 // create group
    var group = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "main_group")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

Then scaling for the x axis,

```
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain(0, d3.max(function(d) {
        return d.x_pos
      })).range([0, width]);
```

The width is set with,

```
  var margin = {
            top: 50,
            right: 50,
            bottom: 50,
            left: 50
          },
          width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right, // width=500
          height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom; // height=500
```

When I change the x_pos value to greater than 800 the rendered rect is outside the svg. At the moment at x_pos=525 the top left of the rect is visible.

```
  { 
        // "x_pos": "800",
        "x_pos": "525",
        "y_pos": "300",
        "name": "Dd"
      },
```

I expected the x_pos value in the data to always scale to the range [0, width].

Why is the data not scaling to the range?

[github](https://github.com/shanegibney/d3-v4-Basic-Data-Binding) and gh-pages [demo](https://shanegibney.github.io/d3-v4-Basic-Data-Binding/)

```css
    svg {
      border: 2px solid gray;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>
  <div id="box">
  </div>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    data = [{
        "x_pos": "100",
        "y_pos": "400",
        "name": "Aa"
      },
      {
        "x_pos": "200",
        "y_pos": "200",
        "name": "Bb"
      },
      {
        "x_pos": "300",
        "y_pos": "100",
        "name": "Cc"
      },
      {
        // "x_pos": "300",
        "x_pos": "525",
        "y_pos": "300",
        "name": "Dd"
      },
      {
        "x_pos": "0",
        "y_pos": "0",
        "name": "Ee"
      }
    ]

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.x_pos = +d.x_pos;
      d.y_pos = +d.y_pos;
    });

    var margin = {
        top: 50,
        right: 50,
        bottom: 50,
        left: 50
      },
      width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right, // width=500
      height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom; // height=500

    var x = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain(0, d3.max(function(d) {
        return d.x_pos
      })).range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d.y_pos
      })]).range([height, 0]);

    var svg = d3.select("#box")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

    // create group
    var group = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "main_group")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // bind the data
    var boxes = group.selectAll("boxes")
      .data(data)
      .enter();

    // add rects
    boxes.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "boxes")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return d.x_pos
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return d.y_pos
      })
      .attr("rx", "5px")
      .attr("width", 60)
      .attr("height", 20)
      .attr("stroke", "darkgray")
      .attr("fill", "lightblue");

    // add text
    boxes.append("text")
      .attr("class", "legend_text")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return d.x_pos
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return d.y_pos
      })
      .attr("dx", "0.5em")
      .attr("dy", "1.0em")
      .style("font-weight", "bold")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      });

    // add text coordinates
    boxes.append("text")
      .attr("class", "legend_text")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return d.x_pos
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return d.y_pos
      })
      .attr("dx", "-2.5em")
      .attr("dy", "-.5em")
      .style("font-weight", "bold")
      .text(function(d) {
        return "(" + d.x_pos + ", " + d.y_pos + ")";
      });
  </script>
```

Comment: you might have to add clamp(true) after the range.

Comment: after changing the x-pos to 800, will your max value in domain is changing to 800

Comment: @HarshaVardhan it's not actually. So you mean that the max value would render a rect which is just outside the svg and therefore I would never see it. To test that, I changed the x_pos to say 1000 then even if I can't see that rect, all the others should be scaled appropriately and so get squashed to the left. But that isn't happening. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is very simple: you are not using any scale to position the rectangles:

```
.attr("x", function(d) {
    return d.x_pos
})
```

Solution: Use your scale.

```
.attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.x_pos)
    //     ^--- scale here
})
```

Also, you're not setting your domain correctly. It should be:

```
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d.x_pos
    })]).range([0, width]);
```

Here is your code with those changes:

```css
svg {
      border: 2px solid gray;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>
  <div id="box">
  </div>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    data = [{
        "x_pos": "100",
        "y_pos": "400",
        "name": "Aa"
      },
      {
        "x_pos": "200",
        "y_pos": "200",
        "name": "Bb"
      },
      {
        "x_pos": "300",
        "y_pos": "100",
        "name": "Cc"
      },
      {
        // "x_pos": "300",
        "x_pos": "525",
        "y_pos": "300",
        "name": "Dd"
      },
      {
        "x_pos": "0",
        "y_pos": "0",
        "name": "Ee"
      }
    ]

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.x_pos = +d.x_pos;
      d.y_pos = +d.y_pos;
    });

    var margin = {
        top: 50,
        right: 50,
        bottom: 50,
        left: 50
      },
      width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right, // width=500
      height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom; // height=500

    var x = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d.x_pos
      })]).range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d.y_pos
      })]).range([height, 0]);

    var svg = d3.select("#box")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

    // create group
    var group = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "main_group")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // bind the data
    var boxes = group.selectAll("boxes")
      .data(data)
      .enter();

    // add rects
    boxes.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "boxes")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.x_pos)
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.y_pos)
      })
      .attr("rx", "5px")
      .attr("width", 60)
      .attr("height", 20)
      .attr("stroke", "darkgray")
      .attr("fill", "lightblue");

    // add text
    boxes.append("text")
      .attr("class", "legend_text")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.x_pos)
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.y_pos)
      })
      .attr("dx", "0.5em")
      .attr("dy", "1.0em")
      .style("font-weight", "bold")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      });

    // add text coordinates
    boxes.append("text")
      .attr("class", "legend_text")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.x_pos)
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.y_pos)
      })
      .attr("dx", "-2.5em")
      .attr("dy", "-.5em")
      .style("font-weight", "bold")
      .text(function(d) {
        return "(" + d.x_pos + ", " + d.y_pos + ")";
      });
  </script>
```

Comment: Ah yes I see it now Gerardo. Thank you very much for looking at this.

Comment: No worries. That's why **names** are so important in computer languages: don't name it `var x`, it's confusing and not clear. Name it `var xScale` or `var horizontalScale`.